How to add character customization to my app? (graphics positioned and scaled relative to another)
So, basically, I want to add an SVG graphic character in my app and I want to swap it's clothes and accessories.
I tried achieving this using a combination of a Stack(), Positioned(), and SizedBox() widget, but it doesn't scale correctly when I want to change its size.
Is there some advanced widgets to handle cases like that? I asked Gemini, and it suggested using a CustomPainter, but I don't know how to use that and weather that is the best approach or not? I also considered to alter the SVG code directly or use css but I don't know how I could do that.
This is my approach:
return Expanded(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: size, height: size,

        child: Stack(
          children: [

            //body
            SvgPicture.asset("assets/char/body.svg"),

            //clothes
            Positioned(
              top: 175, left: 14.2,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: size/1.38, width: size/1.38,

                child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/char/clothes/clothe_1.svg"),
              ),
            ),

          ]),
      ),
    );


(I want to add clothes on the body part, and glasses on the face, then I should freely use this character or swap the clothes)

Learning SVG will be worth every effort; Clothes should just be <g> elements visibile or not

I assume  means a group? I checked the svg file and it doesn't have any groups despite grouping the elements in Figma. I may do this manually but I'm kinda lost here, how can I manipulate this behavior in code, can you give an example?

Learn https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/
